# How to refresh an already expired token with Laravel passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Yesterday my application's Oauth-access-tokens has been expired and that token is linked to more than five thousand devices (android) and now they are all rejected by Laravel passport. so is there any way to use that same token again or increase the time of that expired token. so that I don't need to change my application's token and release it again which it takes some time.

Comment: Do you have the refresh token that was issued with your access token?

Comment: Yes I still have it in database

Comment: You should be able to send the refresh token using the refresh grant and obtain a new access token.